# pagination not working on custom-taxonomy template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, pagination, urls

I created custom taxonomy and registered it with "Pages" with the following code

```
//hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_Offer_Categorys_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

//create a custom taxonomy name it Offer Categorys for your posts

function create_Offer_Categorys_hierarchical_taxonomy() {

// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
//first do the translations part for GUI

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Offer Category', 'offer Categories general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Offer Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Offer Category' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Offer Categorys' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Offer Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Offer Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Offer Category' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Offer Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Offer Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Offer Category Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Offer Category' ),
  );    

// Now register the taxonomy

  register_taxonomy('offer-category',array('page'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'offer-category' ),
  ));

}
```

Then I created a template file named **taxonomy-offer-category.php**

Issue is pagination is not working as it should be. After writing the code of pagination, paging url coming like this '/**offer-category/automobile/page/2**', etc

but this page is giving error (404) but when I manually hit url like

**/offer-category/automobile?page=2** then this gives the result.I dont know whats the issue. below is the code for pagination

```
$term_id=get_queried_object()->term_id;
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
// echo $paged; 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
        'paged'    => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => '1',        
    'tax_query' => array(       
        array(  'taxonomy' => 'offer-category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $term_id

                    )   
    ),
);
wp_reset_query();
//$page_args=array('post_type' => 'page');
$query = new WP_Query($args);




$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                $links = paginate_links( array(

                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
                    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text'    => '<',
                    'next_text'    => '>',
                    'type' => 'array'
                ) );
```

I have tried all the possible answers of google like using format, using paged instead of page etc and this issue is a long time back issue and I dont know whether it is fixed or not. Can you guys please help me in that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is at the root of the domain (something like http://www.example.com), find the location `/` block inside the configuration file, and add the following line to it.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Here, Nginx checks for the existence of a file at the URL (`$uri`), then for a directory (`$uri/`). If it doesn’t find a directory or a file, it performs an internal redirect to `/index.php` passing the query string arguments as parameters.

It should look like this after the edits :

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

If your site is in a subfolder (say `/site`), you’ll have to add an extra location `/site/` block to your configuration file :

```
location /site/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site/index.php?$args;
}
```

After you have finished making the changes in the configuration file, reload the nginx configuration by :

```
nginx -s reload
```

Wordpress’ pretty permalinks should work fine now.

I found this answer [here](http://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/)
And here are some other helpful likns-

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx
2. http://www.lowendguide.com/3/webservers/wordpress-permalinks-with-nginx/
3. https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Comment: I have tried that but still not working, I tried with default permalink as well

Comment: Are you using **Apache ** or **NGINX** ? @BhuvneshGupta

Comment: I am using NGINX

Comment: That's why it is not working. You need to manually modify the rewrite rule for **NGINX**.

Comment: how and what to do for that?

Comment: Check updated answer. @BhuvneshGupta

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get it exactly where to write that code? I am running multisite in wordpress and this is one of the sub site of multisite wordpress. so its url is like http://sitedomain.com/offe/wp-admin   . Can you please tell me now in which file I have to write code

Comment: well I tried on localhost (apache) as well same code but not working. now what we can do?